# Add some infomation to Auth lararvel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a API with Laravel. This API when execute will save information to Auth class.

For example, i got field `$tableId`, I want to save this to Auth, then I can use something like `Auth::table()` and it give me `tableId`. I have tried `Auth::user()->table_id = $tableId` but it only works in this API. When I tried `Auth::user()` in another API, there was no `table_id` field returned.

So, anyone has solution?

Comment: Does the $tableId stored on your Database?

Comment: please upload  your controller and model and rout ti help you

Comment: @MohamedRaza no , it is a field generated in api controller

Comment: @simpsons3 checkout this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63112745/11043676

Answer (score -1):

You can store information to auth via Register controller

**First update your UserModel**

`app->User`

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'tableid'
];
```

**Second Insert the Table id via controller**

`app->http->controllers->auth->registerController`

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'tableId' => 1 // your table id
    ]);
}
```

**To get Tabled**

```
Auth::user()->tableID->get()
```

Comment: I can see in you code that you added ```tableId``` field in ```users``` table, doesn't you?

Comment: you get user information by using `users` table isn't it? so why can't you put your tableId in users table?. This the solution for your question @simpsons3